# Cisco Config Parser multiple lines

Tags: python, cisco, cisco-ios, ciscoconfparse

I am working on a parse for verifying configs for wlan controllers and I thought I had something.  I usually use show commands but all I have available are the configs in a text format.

I have some configs that have either or of these lines.  They are pulled and saved with putty.

```
VLAN........................ 
..................... 900      



VLAN............................................. 900
```

Code I am using is rather simple

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

parse = CiscoConfParse('config.txt', syntax='ios')

vlan = parse.find_objects(r'^VLAN')
#print(vlan)
vlan_id = vlan[0]
print(" VLAN: {0}".format(vlan_id.text))
```

if in the config it is one line I can trim it up and get the vlan id, but if it is in two lines I do not get the vlan id.

With this in the config I do not get a vlan id

```
VLAN........................ 
..................... 900
```

This I do

```
VLAN............................................. 900
```

I am looking for a way just to get the vlan id on either way it is formatted in the conig.

Thank you

Comment: This is more a problem with how you're retrieving the file over putty than how you're parsing it. The parsing is fine; the _retrieval_ is broken. Make sure the terminal width is correctly set, as one potential place to start.

Comment: (and how to get Cisco IOS to give you the data in its desired form is more a [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) question than a Stack Overflow one).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree that the terminal width associated with a given session could be the issue.  But the OP could use a regular expression to parse any config files already extracted.  e.g., (VLAN)(.*\n.*)(\d{1,6})|(VLAN)(.*)(\d{1,6})

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, his parser line says `syntax="ios"`, but the output is actually not from IOS.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need [CiscoConfParse()](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse)... just use `split()`

This would work...

```py
 $ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input1 = "VLAN............................................. 900"
>>> input2 = """VLAN........................
... ..................... 900"""
>>>
>>> input1.split()[-1]
'900'
>>>
>>> input2.split()[-1]
'900'
>>>
```